# How to find the following condition on the domain of conjugate function of negative geometric mean?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The conjugate function of the negative geometric mean ($f(x)=-(\prod_{i}^{n} x_i)^{1/n}$ over $R^n_{++}$) is given as follows $$f^*(y)=\sup_{x}\left(x^Ty+(\prod_{i}^{n} x_i)^{1/n}\right).$$ I know that the domain of the function must satisfy $y\preceq 0$. But, for this function how to get the following condition on the domain of the conjugate function $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n |y_i|\right)^{1/n}> \frac{1}{n}. $$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you use $\nleq$ instead of $>$?

Comment: can you creatively apply the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @LinAlg actually by applying AM-GM inequality I can show that if $\right (\prod_{i=1}^n |y_i| \left)^{1/n} \geq 1/n$ then the function has a value zero. But I can not see how to deduce that the other case makes it go to infinity. I have seen an example in convex optimization book (By Boyd and Vandenberghe) that it goes to infinity if we assume that $\right(\prod_{i=1}^n|y_i|\left)^{1/n}< 1/n$ but my main problem is how to deduce this result.

Comment: @LinAlg ok I change it to $>$ sign instead of $\leq$ sign

Comment: @LinAlg can you please provide a reference that has more detailed explanation?

Comment: See solutions to 3(e) in https://www.ece.nus.edu.sg/stfpage/vtan/ee5138/sol4.pdf

Comment: @max_zorn Thank you for your comment. I have seen that solution before. But as you can see in that solution they assume certain values of $x$ and then show the validity of the condition on domain of $y$. But if we consider the case $n=1$. Then we know that $f^*(y)=\max_x\{xy-x\}=\max_x\{x(y-1)\}$. In this situation, we do not assume any specific value of $x$ but still we can say, by looking at this equation, that $y<1$. Why this can not be said by just looking at the equation that correspond to general values of $n$? That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the original question but rather an answer to the original poster's comment directed at me. (Placed as answer for space reasons.)

Suppose that $n=1$.
Then
$$f^*(y)=\sup_{x>0}\big(y\cdot x + x\big)
= \sup_{x>0}(y+1)x.$$
Now let us evaluate this supremum.
*Case 1:* If $y>-1$, i.e., $y+1>0$, then $f^*(y)\geq (y+1)x\to+\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$.
*Case 2:* If $y=-1$, then $y+1=0$ and clearly $f^*(y)=0$.
*Case 3:* If $y<-1$, then $y+1<0$. Hence $(y+1)x<0$ when $x>0$, and this implies $f^*(y)\leq 0$. However, if $x\to 0^+$, then $(y+1)x\to 0^-$ and so $f^*(y)=0$.

Altogether, 
$$f^*(y) = \begin{cases} 
0, &\text{if $y\leq -1$;}\\
+\infty, &\text{if $y>-1$}
\end{cases}.$$

So, for $n=1$, it is **not true** that $|y|>1$ when $y$ is in the domain of $f^*$.